# spec'ing private methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have some private methods in my rails models. I want to spec it out seperately (use rspec).

I do something like this

```
  class TestModelA < ModelA
    def public_wrapper_method_A
      private_method_A_from_ModelA
    end
  end
```

and I write specs for TestModelA#public_wrapper_method_A

I think there is good case for writing specs for private methods.

What is the best way of writing tests for these private methods.

what do you guys think ? pros/cons?

Answer (score 1):

I usually set aside a `context` group for private methods and then setup a `describes` block for each method. Within the block I define a helper method to call the private method and then the `it` blocks use the `call_xxx` method to get to the private method.

```
context "private methods" do
  describe "#some_private_method" do
    def call_some_private_method
      some_obj.send(:some_private_method)
    end

    it "should return 'something'" do
      call_some_private_method.should == 'something'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to wrap your class to test private methods. You can use [send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send) instead.

```
object.send(:foo_private_method)
```